# Calling a function that add controls to the Form from Class

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I am trying to add some controls at runtime to my Form. I have created a function to add the controls to the Form inside its coding area. I have to call the function from a class so that the values can be used in many other forms. Here is the code:

**In the class:**

```
    public void AddControl(string ControlTxt)
    {
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        frm1.AddButton(ControlTxt);
    }
```

**In the Form:**

```
    public  void AddButton(string TxtToDisplay)
    {

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Size = new Size(50, 50);
        btn.Location = new Point(10, yPos);
        yPos = yPos + btn.Height + 10;
        btn.Text = TxtToDisplay;
        btn.Visible = true;
        this.Controls.Add(btn);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 cls1 = new Class1();
        cls1.AddControl("Hello");
    }
```

When I clicked on `button1` the code does not work and it's not showing any exceptions.
How do I call the `AddButton` function of the Form from the class?

Answer (score 2):

If your main form is an new off your custom Form class, you could use the this.AddButton().

Now you are making a new initialisation of a Form, but you're not showing it anywhere.

Actually, that is also the reason why you don't receive an error. The application works as programmed, but your newly created form is never set to a window, or set visible.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new form with every click(instead of using the current form), I would do it this way (while trying to be close to your code):

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public static void AddControl(Form form, string controlTxt)
    {
        form.AddButton(form, controlTxt);
    }

    public static void AddButton(string form, string TxtToDisplay)
    {

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Size = new Size(50, 50);
        btn.Location = new Point(10, yPos);
        yPos = yPos + btn.Height + 10;
        btn.Text = TxtToDisplay;
        btn.Visible = true;
        form.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeClass.AddControl(this, "Hello");
}
```